# Get Product Image Array - Email Order Confirmation

Tags: magento-1.9, email, image, array

I'm developing a new order conformation page in `magento 1.9.3` and I have everything working yet I can't seem to get the image from this here,

`'imgUrl' => Mage::getModel('catalog/product_media_config')->getMediaUrl( $_product->getThumbnail()),`

what I get as a result is,

`< img src="https://mycompany.com/media/catalog/product/" alt="product title works">`

I can't seem to get this straight, can anyone help me understand why this isn't working.

my full code is everything else works fine but I can't seem to get the full path of the image correctly

```
$_order = $this->getOrder();

if ($_order){
$wa_data = array(
'symbol' => Mage::app()->getLocale()->currency(Mage::app()->getStore()
  ->getCurrentCurrencyCode())->getSymbol(),
 'items' => $_order->getAllItems(),

);

foreach ($wa_data['items'] as $key => $value) {
$vars = get_object_vars ($value);
$_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
->setStoreId($value->getOrder()->getStoreId())
->load($value->getProductId());
$item = array(
'url' => $_product->getProductUrl(),
'imgUrl' => Mage::getModel('catalog/product_media_config')->getMediaUrl( 
$_product->getThumbnail()),
'name' => $value->getName(),
'sku' => $vars['_data']['sku'],
'description' => $vars['_data']['description'],
'number' => $vars ['_data']['product_id'],
'qty' => intval($vars['_data']['qty_ordered']),
'price' => $wa_data['symbol'] . ' ' . intval($vars['_data']['base_price']),
'total' => $wa_data['symbol'] . ' ' . intval($vars['_data']
['base_row_total']),
);
$wa_data['items'][$key] = $item;
}

}else{
$wa_data = array(
'symbol' => Mage::app()->getLocale()->currency(Mage::app()->getStore()
  ->getCurrentCurrencyCode())->getSymbol(),
);
for($i=0; $i < 5; $i++) {
$item = array(
'url' => '#',
'imgUrl' => 'https://www.google.ru/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_120x44dp.png',
'name' => 'Product' . $i,
'sku' => "SKU {$i}",
'description' => "Description {$i} Maecenas faucibus mollis interdum. Nulla 
vitae elit libero, a pharetra augue. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo",
'number' => "123456number{$i}",
'price' => ($i+1) * 49,
'qty' => $i+1,
'total' => $wa_data['symbol'] . ' ' . (($i+1) * ($i+1) * 49),
);
$wa_data['items'][$i] = $item;
}
}; ?>
```

Comment: hi let's try like this  echo  Mage::helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->resize(50,50);

Comment: I get the /placeholder/small_image.jpg placeholder image. it's working but I need to trouble shoot why only the place holder image is showing up.

Answer (score 0):

after much review I was able to get this working by simply using,

```
 Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_media_config')->getMediaUrl($_product->getThumbnail()),
```

**getSingleton** instead of **getModel** and it worked perfect, both the url and thumbnail.